# How to sum a multiple-line array of Boolean value into an one-line array?

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, office365

Dear Excel masters please take a look. Here's the formula that I want to use:

```
Filter(A1:A4,ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"},B2:B4)))
```

What ISNUMBER returned is a table of array that Filter function doesn't recognize. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the comma represents the separator for **horizontal** arrays for your version of Excel:

`=LET(ζ,{"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"},FILTER(A1:A4,MMULT(N(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(ζ,B1:B4))),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(ζ))),""))`

Answer (score 2):

You could nest `BYROW()`:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A4,BYROW(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg"},B1:B4)),LAMBDA(a,SUM(--a))))
```

Note that I did expect you to have a typo in the `B2:B4` range reference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't find BYROW function in Excel. Is it define by VBA or third party add-ins required? PS. Thanks for pointing out my typo. It was supposed to be A1:B4

Comment: @C.G., no `BYROW()` is just another excel function for ms365. See the [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb). Despite it being relatively new, you should have access. See if an update is available under File > Account > Office Updates.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft 365 Version2202 (Build 14931.20724). Seems like it's not up to date and hasn't got the newest function but this is the latest version I can use. My Office suite and computer is managed by my company and I can't update anything at will. Sigh.